# Create a simple shrinking square fractal with Inkscape and Tiled Clones

Tags: inkscape, tiles

How can I create an image like this in Inkscape? (squares only, ignore the little hairs)
[image]

I'm trying to start with a square, then use Tiled clones to repeat the pattern several times, but I can't seem to find the correct combo of shift and scale settings to get this to work!

Comment: What is the problem? Centering the upper right corner in the middle of the original, keeping the border width constant, ...?

Comment: All of it. I can't get them to shrink 50% or any other consistent scaling) each time, and I can't get them to position either. I'm not worried about border.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use Tiled Clones to create that.

Try this instead:

1. Switch on snapping options as shown in the example below
2. Open the Transform panel, and click on the Scale tab. Set the scaling as desired.
3. Create a square with a black stroke and filled white
4. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to make a clone
5. Hit the *Apply* button in the Scale panel.
6. Move the square until the corner snaps to the object rotation center of the smaller square below it.
7. Repeat steps 4 to 6 until finished.

[image]